# Interator string PHP

Tags: php

I have the following result
[image]

for ex

serie0, serie1, serie2 etc ...
how to make a loop in php, I've try

```
for($i = 0; $i < count; $i++) {
    echo $request[`serie{$i}`];
}
```

any idea please ?

Comment: Use double quotes (not backticks) in PHP when you want variable substitution. `echo $request["serie{$i}"];`

Comment: Backticks are for shell execution in PHP. See the second answer in the duplicate.

Comment: its ok, resolve my problem thanks